# Azure APIM - Support awverify

Tags: azure-api-management

Does Azure APIM support custom domain verification based on awverify TXT records similiar to [Azure websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain#create-domain-verification-record) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But dedicated tiers of APIM do not require you to validate domain at all, only consumption tier requires CNAME record.